Terraform Provider map[string]interface{}{} challenge
I have a challenge creating a payload for a terraform provider resource:
The API I am talking to expects values like this:
    "IPv4Addresses": 
    [      
      {
        "SubnetMask": "255.255.248.0",
        "AddressOrigin": "DHCP",
        "Gateway": "10.14.104.1",
        "Address": "10.14.105.9"
      }
    ],


    "DHCPv4":     {
      "UseStaticRoutes": true,
      "UseGateway": true,
      "UseDNSServers": true,
      "UseDomainName": true,
      "UseNTPServers": false,
      "DHCPEnabled": true
    },

The difference is that DHCPv4 isn't and JSON array like IPv4Addresses for example. I can address the IPv4Addresses using:
if v, ok := d.GetOk("ipv4_static_address"); ok {
  m["IPv4StaticAddresses"] = []map[string]interface{}{
    {
    "Address":    v.(*schema.Set).List()[0].(map[string]interface{})["address"],
    "SubnetMask": v.(*schema.Set).List()[0].(map[string]interface{})["subnet_mask"],
    "Gateway":    v.(*schema.Set).List()[0].(map[string]interface{})["gateway"],
    },
  }
}

Which becomes a map like this:
map[IPv4StaticAddresses:[map[Address:10.100.32.185 Gateway:10.100.32.129 SubnetMask:255.255.255.192]]]

But the DHCPv4 payload should look more like this.
map[DHCPv4:[Enabled:true UseNTPServers:true]]

I can't figure out how to not have a map in a map :(
I tried to address the values directly but the keys aren't accessible in a map. I tried to map the values as single items but that didn't work either.

Yeah I looked at this and converting the payload to JSON works:
payload, _ := toJSON(m)
I was hoping for something like:
if v, ok := d.GetOk("dhcp_v4"); ok {
  m["DHCPv4"] = []map[string]interface{}{
    {
    "Enabled":    v.(*schema.Set).List()[0]["enabled"],
    "UseDNSServer": v.(*schema.Set).List()[0]["use_dns"],
    },
  }
}

But the indexing doesn't work as it's a JSON object of string: string.
